# Character class variable prints multiple lines in dialog box in R

Tags: r

In R, I want the user to provide information through a dialog box (i.e., `svDialogs'` `dlgInput`). However, in order to avoid the user providing double data, I want to list, in mentioned dialog box, the information that already exists. The issue is that if the variable has more than one data, more than one line appears (as many as there are data).

For example, using the following code:

```
library(svDialogs)
temp = c("one", "two", "three")
userInput <-  dlgInput(paste("Enter info (these already exist:", temp, ")"))$res
```

gives me a dialog box with the following lines above the user input field:

```
Enter info (these already exist: one)
Enter info (these already exist: two)
Enter info (these already exist: three)
```

Whereas, what I would like is:

```
Enter info (these already exist: one, two, three)
```

I tried the following 2 alternatives, both gave the same result as `paste()`:

```
sprintf("Enter a ticker (these are already loaded: %s)", temp)
stringr::str_glue("Hi Have a very nice ${temp} !")
```

The following alternatives almost worked, but they give me a strange `"Hi Have a very nice c(\"one\", \"two\", \"three\") !"` of which I don't know how to strip the `c(\)` and the quotes:

```
fn$paste("Enter a ticker (these are already loaded: $temp)") #requires library(gsubfn)
stringr::str_interp("Hi Have a very nice ${temp} !")
str_interp("Hi Have a very nice ${temp} !")
```

My question:

- How do I have to redact `dlgInput(paste("Enter info (these already exist:", temp, ")"))$res` so that the output renders `Enter info (these already exist: one, two, three)`?

---

System used:

- R version: 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
- RStudio version: 1.4.1717
- OS: macOS Catalina version 10.15.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these functions are vectorised, so they produce one output per input. You want to *collapse* the inputs, *before* passing them to any of these functions. This can be e.g. via `toString`:

```
userInput <-  dlgInput(paste("Enter info (these already exist:", toString(temp), ")"))$res
```

You could also use `paste(temp, collapse = ', ')` to get the same result. Note that you will still need *two* (nested) calls of `paste`, a single call isn’t sufficient here.

When using ‘glue’, you can achieve the same via [`glue_collapse`](https://glue.tidyverse.org/reference/glue_collapse.html) or by implementing and using a [collapse transformer](https://glue.tidyverse.org/articles/transformers.html#collapse-transformer).